# unexpected predict() result for linear regression in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, prediction

I'm working on a code that predict an hourly rental rates of bikes based on historical data. Data have many attributes (shown below), and to fit the model I used linear regressions models , then I predicted the results and it showed me somehow unexpected results, like negative values and decimal numbers.

here is the head of my train object:

```
> head(train)
             datetime season holiday workingday weather temp  atemp humidity windspeed casual registered count hour weekday month year
1 2011-01-01 00:00:00      1       0          0       1 9.84 14.395       81    0.0000      3         13    16    0       6     0 2011
2 2011-01-01 01:00:00      1       0          0       1 9.02 13.635       80    0.0000      8         32    40    1       6     0 2011
3 2011-01-01 02:00:00      1       0          0       1 9.02 13.635       80    0.0000      5         27    32    2       6     0 2011
4 2011-01-01 03:00:00      1       0          0       1 9.84 14.395       75    0.0000      3         10    13    3       6     0 2011
5 2011-01-01 04:00:00      1       0          0       1 9.84 14.395       75    0.0000      0          1     1    4       6     0 2011
6 2011-01-01 05:00:00      1       0          0       2 9.84 12.880       75    6.0032      0          1     1    5       6     0 2011
    4    3       6     0 2011
    5    4       6     0 2011
    6    5       6     0 2011
```

note the column 'count', our response variable.

Here I create a model excluding some variables.

```
> fit = glm(count ~ season + holiday + workingday + weather + temp + humidity + hour+ weekday+ month +year , data = train)
```

Now I created a new object to use it on predictions, putting all the variables from the model above:

```
> newdata = train[,c(2,3,4,5,6,8,13,14,15,16)]
```

Finally, I run predict() and store results in new column in newdata

```
newdata$count <- predict(fit, newdata)
```

and guess what ?

```
> head(newdata)
      season holiday workingday weather  temp humidity hour weekday month year       count
10887      1       0          1       1 10.66       56    0       4     0 2011 -30.0948283
10888      1       0          1       1 10.66       56    1       4     0 2011 -22.6578089
10889      1       0          1       1 10.66       56    2       4     0 2011 -15.2207896
10890      1       0          1       1 10.66       56    3       4     0 2011  -7.7837702
10891      1       0          1       1 10.66       56    4       4     0 2011  -0.3467508
10892      1       0          1       1  9.84       60    5       4     0 2011  -8.7999703
> tail(newdata)
      season holiday workingday weather  temp humidity hour weekday month year     count
11138      1       0          1       2  6.56       55   18       1     0 2011  69.14183
11139      1       0          1       1 12.30       61   19       1     0 2011 113.75079
11140      1       0          1       3  6.56       59   20       1     0 2011  40.03549
11141      1       0          1       3  6.56       59   21       1     0 2011  47.47251
11142      1       0          1       2  6.56       59   22       1     0 2011  90.75131
11143      1       0          1       2  6.56       64   23       1     0 2011  88.01509
```

- there is one thing I forgot to mention. Training set includes hourly rentals for the first 19 days of a given month, and the test data we want to predict are the remaining days. I tried creating a model for only the first month (as it should be, but not illustrated in the code above) but the results still have strange negative and decimals.

I didn't expect to see negative values and decimals. Am I doing something wrong ?

*(Further, I think values are not accurate due to the model I use, but I am not concerned with the model itself as I am concerned with learning the basics of modelling.)*

Comment: You get these results because you are fitting a linear model. You clearly want to fit a count model, so you should experiment with setting `family=poisson()` or `family=quaispoisson`. See the examples at `?family`.

Comment: That's great help. I've got more realistic counts (like 3's to 5's) .... but still got decimals in my results!

Comment: One more thing, do you suggest using another model that would give more reasonable/accurate results ?

Comment: It is just a model, so the decimals are expected.  Use `round()` if you want these as integers.

Comment: Yes it's. and I think even negative values might be converted to 0 since the model is blind and doesn't know that this variable is count.

Comment: You shouldn't get negative values if you use the correct family.

Comment: It looks like you have time series data. You should treat it as such. I suggest to consult a statistician.

Comment: @Andrie its not that the model is *linear* that produces negative predictions so much that the response is *Gaussian* and hence unbounded. Even a Poisson model is still *linear* (there's a clue in the name "Generalised Linear Model") but via an appropriate transform and variance structure. You probably knew that anyway.

Comment: @Spacedman Thank you for fixing my lazy way of expressing myself./